# What are some other ways to say: "I expected that to be the case."?

Tags: idioms, expressions

I need to know other natural ways to say: 'I expected that (=what you just said) is the case.'

Example:

Jessy: Do you know who left that half-eaten sandwich on the table?

Edd: Robert did. I saw him eating there last night, and he was the last person to eat here.

Jessy: I expected that to be the case. This guy is so lazy!

Comment: "That is what I expected." or "I expected that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider

- I thought so.
- I thought as much.
- I figured.
- I figured as much.
- Figures.

You might even consider

- *Typical!*
- *That's just like him!*
- *I'm not surprised.*

Although these seem to suggest that you are not surprised, not so much that you expected it.